# Adding a DC bias to an AC signal for amplification and measurement

Tags: signal, signal-processing, coupling, biasing

I am trying to add a DC bias to this AC signal, but for some reason the schematics I found online for this do not work. The AC coupling is not happening.

I have simulated the circuit here: http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5315107213279232

Or screenshot here:
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgJDhN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please embed a proper schematic needed, that's unreadable.

Comment: @replete: An understatement, that link is showing a black box to me.

Comment: Besides not really knowing what you do, we also don't know what "does not work" means for you specifically (i.e. what the desired outcome is) as well as *why* you are doing this, since often people go the other way round for measuring: they remove any dc offset to properly study the ac riding on top of it

Comment: Ok, I edited the OP. The desired outcome would be all the lines (green, orange and blue) to oscillate. But for some reason, at least in that simulator, not even the orange line oscillates, meaning that the AC coupling of the AC source is failing.

Comment: You might want to see an oscillating signal on these lines, but you don't want them "to oscillate". It may sound like nit-picking but there's a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's circuit.*

- You have biased the op-amp input at 2.5 V DC.
- You have configured the amplifier as non-inverting with a gain of ten.
- Output will try to go to 25 V.
- You are powering the amplifier with only 5 V so it has saturated.

I think you are expecting it to amplify the AC but not the DC component.

Comment: Yes, the gain is totally wrong. What I am really missing here is why the orange line (the biased op-amp input) is not oscillating.

Comment: Yes, I want to amplify the AC signal, biasing from -333mV and 333mV to positive values between 0-5V

Comment: I've cleaned up your CircuitLab schematic. Run the simulation on that and you'll see that you get a 55 mV peak at NODE1. (CircuitLab doesn't like spaces in node names.) Note that C1 has an impedance of \$ \frac {1}{2  \pi fC} = 3k3 \$ at 50 Hz so it forms a 7:1 divider with the parallel 1k resistors.